# Keep viewport size static in mobile web browsers

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-safari, viewport

Stack Overflow.

On my website (http://win3movement.org), I have an image element which is the size of the viewport of the browser. On mobile safari and others, however, when the URL box up top shrinks, it also enlarges the viewport size, causing the image element to "readjust." Is there a way in which I can keep the viewport size from changing, make the "initial" viewport size the permanent size for the image? I don't want the element to change size even if the viewport changes sizes; I want the element to remain the size of the "initial" viewport.

The code:

***html***:
  `<div class="block block-large cover-background flex flex-middle **height-viewport** contrast" style="background-image: url(http://win3movement.org/images/win3header_blank_.jpg)">
    ...
  </div>`

***css***:
`.uk-block {padding-top: 50px;padding-bottom: 50px;}

.block-large {padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;}

.cover-background {background-position: 50% 50%;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;}

.flex {display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;}
.flex-middle {-ms-flex-align: center;-webkit-align-items: center;align-items: center;}

.height-viewport {height: 100vh;min-height: 600px;}`

Thank you!

Comment: Width:100% overflow:hidden; height:100% . please post your code and better describe what you really want and what went wrong

Comment: @Jonasw updated my question

Comment: @Jonasw not quite sure what to call it though. If you view my site in Mobile Safari, the url "bar" shrinks after scrolling. This also enlarges the viewport, which in turn enlarges my image element, which I do not want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

But when the toolbar disappears, the site needs to fill more space, doesnt it?
You could solve this with media queries, but as websites are not designed for one device, but for all of them, that will get complicated. So what about this solution: we add the image with a fixed size and crop it to the browser windows size.
To solve the scrolling effect, we stick our container to the bottom.
When the bar disappears, the additional space should be added at the top

```
<div class="container">
<img class="image">
</div>

.container{
width:100℅;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
display:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
}

.image{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
height:auto;
width:auto;
*/depends on your image/*
min-width:500px;
}
```